# C# - IndexOutOfRangeException is unhandled

Tags: c#

I was doing a past paper question at school to adapt some pseudo code which checked if an input ISBN number was valid or not, into C#. I have typed the code in, yet it throws an IndexOutOfRangeException error. I am unsure how that error occurred, as this is my first time using int arrays.

I checked that the index is not negative, and I think the maximum index on the list is less than the list size (I tried changing "Count < 13"  in the for loop to "Count <= 12", but to no avail).

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ISBNExercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] ISBN;
            int Count;
            ISBN = new int[13];
            for(Count = 0; Count < 13; Count++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter next digit of ISBN");
                ISBN[Count] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            int CalculatedDigit = 0;
            int count = 1;
            while (count < 13)
            {
                CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN[Count]; //This is where the error is being thrown.
                Count += 1;
                CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN[Count] * 3;
                Count += 1;
            }
            while (CalculatedDigit >= 10)
            {
                CalculatedDigit -= 10;
            }
            CalculatedDigit = 10 - CalculatedDigit;
            if (CalculatedDigit == 10)
            {
                CalculatedDigit = 0;
            }
            if (CalculatedDigit == ISBN[13])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Valid ISBN");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid ISBN");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your variables; `Count` is not `count`, the former exceeds the array size before the loop

Comment: Use The Debugger Luke!

Comment: I amended the code, but now an exception is being thrown at "if (CalculatedDigit == ISBN[13])". And I'm still a student; I don't understand the debugger yet.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using the `Count` instead of `count` where your error is occurring.

I would suggest naming your variables differently and sticking to the C# convention of using all lower camel case names for variables.  This would have resulted in a compiler error that would have illuminated your issue right away because you would be trying to redefine `count` which you had already definied above.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on this line

```
if (CalculatedDigit == ISBN[13])
```

You define `ISBN` with a length of 13 which means the highest index is 12 because the indexes are zero based.

But even before that your `while` loop is checking `count`, but you are using `Count` inside the loop which already has the value of 13 at that point.

One final point your `while` loop is summing up the 2nd through 13th characters (indexes 1 - 12) and comparing the check digit to presumably the last digit.  I'm guessing you actually want to sum the first 12 digits, so you need to set `count = 0` and check for `count < 12`.

```
int CalculatedDigit = 0;
int count = 0;
while (count < 12)
{
    CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN[count]; //This is where the error is being thrown.
    count += 1;
    CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit + ISBN[count] * 3;
    count += 1;
}
```

or you can just do the following

```
int CalculatedDigit = ISBN.Take(12)
                          .Select((v,i) => i%2 == 0 ? v : v*3)
                          .Sum();           
CalculatedDigit = 10 - (CalculatedDigit % 10);
CalculatedDigit = CalculatedDigit == 10 ? 0 : CalculatedDigit;
```

Your loop that keeps subtracting 10 is really just a modulo (`%`).

Comment: Thanks! I changed the length to 12 and replaced "< 13" to "<= 12" and it now works perfectly.

Comment: @Pinguin I'm not sure I follow.  `< 13` and `<= 12` when incrementing are basically the same.  See my edit for what I'm guessing is a better way to calculate your check digit, unless you're saying the ISBN is actually only 12 digits instead of 13.

Comment: Sorry I said it worked perfectly; it was because the error is gone. But it was marking all ISBN numbers invalid.

Comment: I set count to 0 and now an IndexOutOfRangeException error is being thrown at calculateddigit = calculateddigit + ISBN[count] * 3

Comment: @Pinguin I've updated my answer with an example of how to change your code and fixed my version that uses Linq to multiply the "odd indexed" digits by 3.